# Pixelized VSCode on Hyprland setup

Tags: visual-studio, wayland

I recently installed hyprland on my new arch setup and am using vscode for more than a year but the text is pixelized and it cleary doesn't seem right.

I tried almost every solution like forcing code to run with wayland and i don't know if i did something wrong but nothing worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scaling issue, add

`xwayland { force_zero_scaling = true }`
to your hyprland config file